# Get enough sleep vs. have enough sleep

Tags: grammar

Is it wrong to say "have enough sleep" instead of "get enough sleep"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Have' is a passive word. 'Get' is an active word. For example, you could 'have' a meal and someone else could be involved in giving it to you. You could 'get' a meal and that could mean you were involved in getting it.
However, use of either word is not necessarily incorrect in the context of getting/having enough sleep.